# Nested For Loop Square- Java

Tags: java, for-loop, nested

I am new to Java and I'm working on making a square of two triangles using a nested for loop. It is supposed to look like this:

```
+ + + + + 
* + + + + 
* * + + + 
* * * + + 
* * * * +
```

My code looks like this so far:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {             
for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {               
System.out.print("* ");             
}  
System.out.println();
```

but all it gives me is the star section of the square. I have no idea how to go from here. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited** to add explanation.

The first step is to create a grid of 5 by 5. We can do that by creating two for loops, one within another. The inner for loop will print a row of `*` , and the outer for loop will print a new line after every row.

The next step would be to determine when to print a `+`  instead of a `*` . For your case, a simple greater than (`y > x`) will do the trick.

```
for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
        System.out.print(y > x ? "* " : "+ ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

[image]
*Demo with Desmos Graph Calculator.* 
*Note that the y-axis is inverted, you can use `-y > x` to get the correct orientation*

Comment: Don't give explanationless answer please

Comment: How did you end up creating your account 7 years ago and only using it now ? that's very rare to see

Answer (score 1):

After adding `i` stars, you to add `5-i` plus sign

```
int lineLength = 5;
for (int i = 0; i < lineLength; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        System.out.print("* ");
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < lineLength - i; j++) {
        System.out.print("+ ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

---

You can use `String.repeat` to simplify the code

```
int lineLength = 5;
for (int i = 0; i < lineLength; i++) {
    System.out.println("* ".repeat(i) + "+ ".repeat(lineLength - i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the *[Arrays#fill](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#fill(char%5B%5D,char))* method to pre-populate a 2-dimensional array of *char*.

Then, iterate to replace the corresponding indices with asterisks.

```java
char[][] characters = new char[5][5];
for (char[] row : characters) Arrays.fill(row, '+');
int count = 0;
for (char[] row : characters) {
    for (int index = 0; index < count; index++)
        row[index] = '*';
    count++;
}
int index = 0;
for (char[] row : characters) {
    for (char character : row) {
        if (index++ != 0) System.out.print(" ");
        System.out.print(character);
    }
    index = 0;
    System.out.println();
}
```

Output

```
+ + + + + 
* + + + + 
* * + + + 
* * * + + 
* * * * +
```

Additionally, you can use a method to allow for input values.

```java
void draw(int size, char charA, char charB) {
    char[][] characters = new char[size][size];
    for (char[] row : characters) Arrays.fill(row, charB);
    int count = 0;
    for (char[] row : characters) {
        for (int index = 0; index < count; index++)
            row[index] = charA;
        count++;
    }
    int index = 0;
    for (char[] row : characters) {
        for (char character : row) {
            if (index++ != 0) System.out.print(" ");
            System.out.print(character);
        }
        index = 0;
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Example usage, and output.

```java
draw(20, '@', '-');
```

```
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
@ - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
@ @ - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
@ @ @ - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
@ @ @ @ - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
@ @ @ @ @ - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
@ @ @ @ @ @ - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
@ @ @ @ @ @ @ - - - - - - - - - - - - -
@ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ - - - - - - - - - - - -
@ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ - - - - - - - - - - -
@ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ - - - - - - - - - -
@ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ - - - - - - - - -
@ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ - - - - - - - -
@ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ - - - - - - -
@ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ - - - - - -
@ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ - - - - -
@ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ - - - -
@ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ - - -
@ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ - -
@ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ -
```